# updating one value in State array react native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, state, native

Trying to update one element of an array in this.state I'm getting an (expected ,) error but cant see where I've gone wrong. Do I need to create a temporary array update that, then assign the whole array back to the state

This is essentially what I have

```
this.state = { array: ['a', 'b', 'c'] };

onBack() {
  this.setState({
      array[2]: 'something' 
  });
}
```

Comment: `Do I need to create a temporary array update that, then assign the whole array back to the state`

yes

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu is correct and this approach is the best approach!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't update the state like this.

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Read [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

You can do something like this :

```
let newArray = [...this.state.array];
newArray[2] = 'somethingElse';
this.setState({array: newArray});
```

The above example is using [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

There are multiple ways to modify state, but all the ways should ensure that data is treated as immutable. You can read more about handling state in React [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5)

Comment: upvoted for spread-operator approach, also just for extra knowledge, which will be better for performance direct mutation of state or using spread-operator?

Comment: mutating directly would be faster since you don't have to create a copy, but that would result in an inconsistent state and is something that should never be done. The spread operator basically creates a copy of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Manoj's answer will work, there is another way using the updater function *(funtinal `setState`)* for `setState` (which you can read about [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

```js
onBack() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let newArray = prevState.array
    newArray[2] = "something"
    return { array: newArray }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.assign({});](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let array= Object.assign({}, this.state.array); //creating copy of object

array[2]="something"

this.setState({array});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are bother to set the new updated array on your `currentArray` using spread function, you may use `Array.from(duplicateArray)`

```
let duplicateArray = [...currentArray] //duplicate the array into new array
duplicateArray[index].value = 'x'; // update the field you want to update
setCurrentArray(Array.from(duplicateArray )) //set the new updated array into currentArray
```

I bother with this issue and I just search about and I saw this idea, and it works!
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21734#issuecomment-433885436

Answer (score 0):

## using hooks

```
const [totalSet, setTotalSet] = useState(null);
```

console.log(totalSet); // {sets: Array(3), subscribed: false}

```
setTotalSet(datas => ({
    ...datas,
    sets: updatedSet,
  }));
```

Answer (score -1):

***Create a temporary array update that, then assign the whole array back to the state***

```
var arr = [];
arr = this.state.array;
arr[2] = "something";
this.setState({
    array : arr
});
```

Comment: This is wrong as it mutates the state directly. `arr = this.state.array` does NOT behave as you expect it to.

Comment: I have tried to with my own demo project and its working fine as OP wants.

Comment: Because this is fundamentally wrong and shouldn't be the accepted answer. `arr = this.state.array` does not create a new array, but creates a reference to `state.array`. Try console logging `this.state.array` after you do `arr[2] = "something"` and see what happens.

Comment: You clearly don't understand immutability and what I'm trying to explain so I'm just going to stop.

Comment: Sorry for that, and thanks for clearing the concept of immutable state, I google it and tried to understand the same.

Comment: When you do `arr[2]` you are directly modifying what is in state. This is not a good idea to do. Also, because you are directly modifying state, there is little point of using `setState` as the state has already been changed in the previous step.